# mysql acting very strange with update. please help, I've been stuck on this for a full day now

Tags: mysql, sql-update, paypal-ipn

I've been stuck with this for a full day now and this is the longest I've been stuck coding ever. Please Help me.

I have the following code, it is a paypal ipn URL used to verify an account on a database. I first connect to sql etc. then get the users information from paypal then get the users information from the database. Before paying, the user should have the value of 'unverified' in the user_level column and if 'unverified' it should be updated.

Here is the strange thing that I'm stuck at. The value of user_level is never 'unverified' even though I've checked in the actual database, before running the code, that it is in fact 'unverified'. But when I comment out the mysql_query($u), it gives the value 'unverified'.

What is happening is that it seems to be updating the record before the actual code is being called to check whether to update it or not.

Please help anybody, I would appreciate it greatly.
I

```
$sql_connect = @mysql_connect($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].':3306','root', '******')   or  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('4bkk');

$url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

$postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $postFields .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


if($result=='VERIFIED'){

$log = 'Verfied --- ';

    //get buyers information from PAYPAL checkout
    $email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount3'];
    $plan = $_POST['option_selection1'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $data = mysql_query($q);

    $con = mysql_fetch_array($data); 

    //get buyers information from DATABASE
    $email2 = $con['email'];
    $first_name = $con['first_name'];
    $last_name = $con['last_name'];
    $active = $con['active'];
    $user_level = $con['user_level'];

$log .= $first_name.' ,  '.$last_name.' ,  '.$email2.' ,  '.$active.' ,  '.$user_level.' **************** '.$email ;

if($email2==$email){ //User already has a record 
    if($user_level=='unverified'){ // User unverified, ready for verification
        $log .= 'Emails match, and user is VERIFIED';
        $u = "UPDATE users SET active='verified', user_level='$plan' WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
        $log .= $u;

        mysql_query($u);

    }
    else{ // User is already verified, 
$log .= 'Emails match, BUT user is NOT VERIFIED';


    }
}
else{  //User doesn't have a record
    $log .= 'Emails DONT match, execute update here';
}

$fh = fopen('result_ipn_test.txt', 'w');
//fwrite($fh, $subject.' --- '.$message);
fwrite($fh, $message.' ********** '.$log);
fclose($fh);

}
else
    echo 'INVALID';


mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be cheking for status instead of user-level?

```
if($user_level=='unverified')
```

should be

```
if($active=='unverified')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that the user is not verified in the database then immediately logging that the user IS verified. Also, should this not be checking $active rather than $user_level, as you are placing the value of $plan into $user_level

```
if($user_level=='unverified'){ // User unverified, ready for verification
    $log .= 'Emails match, and user is VERIFIED';
```

Similarly, if the user is listed as 'verified' in the database, you are logging that he is NOT verified:

```
else{ // User is already verified, 
    $log .= 'Emails match, BUT user is NOT VERIFIED';
```

Commenting out the sql query will cause $data to be empty, thus making $user_level empty. $user_level will not match unverified and will result in a log of 'Emails match, BUT user is NOT VERIFIED'

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah mixed up my comments, the variables I get from the database is for example: lalala ,  lalala ,  log2_1351697288_per@ymail.com ,  verified ,  Monthly rather than: lalala ,  lalala ,  log2_1351697288_per@ymail.com ,  ,  unverified which is what it looks like when I viewed it on the database before running the code. Ofcourse it was updated by the code but I logged in the variables before the update script should have ran, meaning in order for the update script to run unverified should have been true.